# Vuex mutation subscription trigger multiple times

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

I'm using vue CLI and I created multiple components

app.vue

```
import home_tpl from './home.vue';

new vue({
    el : '#app',
    components : { home_tpl },
    created(){
        this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
            switch(mutation.type){
                case 'listing':
                    alert();
                break;
        });
    }
})
```

and then I have also a listener to home.vue

home.vue

```
export default{
    created(){
        this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {
            switch(mutation.type){
                case 'listing':
                    alert();
                break;
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is when I do `this.$store.commit('listing',1);` this `this.$store.subscribe((mutation) => {` trigger twice which is the expected behavior since I listen to the event twice from different file, is there a way to make it trigger once only per component?

The reason I call mutation listener to `home.vue` is that because there's an event that I want to run specifically to that component only.

Comment: Instead of subscribing all state changes and only react on quite a few cases, `watch` should be better here? Both `app.vue` and `home.vue` should only watch on the state changes that they're interested.

Comment: @ArieXiao can you show me some code?

Comment: When you say `trigger only once per component`, that implies two triggers for two components that subscribe; but your comment suggests you only want one trigger no matter how many subscriptions. Why subscribe in multiple components when you only want one trigger?

Comment: @tony19 I have to because I have some operations that only applicable to that specific component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample code listen to `listing` change for both `app.vue` and `home.vue`, but according to your posts, it seems they are interested in different kind of changes?

As commented, `watch` should be a better approach if you are only interested in a few changes rather than **all** the changes of the store. Something like:

```js
// home.vue
new vue({
    el : '#app',
    components : { home_tpl },
    created(){
        this.$store.watch((state, getters) => state.stateHomeIsInterested, (newVal, oldVal) => {
            alert()
        })
    }
})

// app.vue
export default{
    created(){
        this.$store.watch((state, getters) => state.stateAppIsInterested, (newVal, oldVal) => {
            alert()
        })
    }
}
```

The difference is:

- the `subscribe` callback will be called whenever there is a mutation in the store (in your case this may waste some unnecessary callback invocations). The callback method receives the mutation and the updated state as arguments
- the `watch` will only react on the changes to the return value of the getter defined in its first argument, and the callback receives the new value and the old value as arguments. You can watch multiple states if required.